# Flask - Errno 13 premission denied

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a small web page whose task is to let a user upload his input file and with uploading I want to execute my calculation program in python which will give me output for the user.

My code looks like this:

```
import os
import os.path
import datetime
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'gro', 'doc', 'docx'])

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
file_time = current_time.isoformat()
proper_filename = file_time

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def run_script():
    subprocess.call(['/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/topologia.py', '/uploads/proper_filename'])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], proper_filename))
        run_script().start()
        return "Thank you for uploading"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Uploading goes well, but the problem is that when I hit upload I get message `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` and the line causing the problem is:

```
subprocess.call(['/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/topologia.py', '/uploads/2014-05-16T22:08:19.522441'])
```

program topologia.py runs from command `python topologia.py input_file`

I have no idea how to solve that problem.

Comment: You are not actually using the Python executable; what happens when you use `import sys`, then `subprocess.call([sys.executable, '/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/topologia.py', '/uploads/proper_filename'])`?

Comment: you should mention the interpreter ['python', '/home/yourprogram', 'argument'] to call

Comment: I have no more errors, but still my program in python doesn't seem to work... I have got no output file

Comment: sorry I answered in same time than Martijn. It's the same thing but his solution is better as precising the full python path

Comment: daouzli i still dont have any output file... And I dont know why, because executing this program from command line works fine. Now I have problem with path - '/uploads/proper_filename' proper_filename is a variable and it seems that it doesnt work that way

Comment: make sure you have rights on the target folder. It's perhaps www-data user that runs from the server while it's martyna that runs from command line

Comment: I have it now :D Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- Your script is probably not marked as executable. You can work around that by using the current Python executable path; use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the path to that.
- You are telling the script to process `/uploads/proper_filename`, but the filename you actually upload your file to is not the same at all; you should use the *contents* of the string referenced by `proper_filename` instead.

Put these two together:

```
import sys
from flask import current_app

def run_script():
    filename = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], proper_filename)
    subprocess.call([
        sys.executable, 
        '/home/martyna/Dropbox/programowanie/project_firefox/topologia.py', 
        filename])
```

You do *not* need to call `.start()` on the result of `run_script()`; you'll get an attribute error on `NoneType`. Just call `run_script()` and be done with it:

```
run_script()
```

Comment: Thank you :) It all works now. I put it up together (comments and your post) and I have my solution

Answer (score 0):

Executing a script from a command line and from a server will not be done with the same permissions.

```
user@mycomputer:~$ ./script
```

In this exemple, `./script` is launched by `user`. So if it does some inputs/outputs, the access rigths will depend on `user` rights.

When it is a server that runs the script, in your case **Flask**, it is probably `www-data` that launch the script. So the access rights are not the same.

So to create a file into a folder the user executing the script should have the permissions on the folder.